# How to move backwards on command in unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am new to unity, tried to make cube move forwards and backwards on command, all working good, except when I try to move it backwards, it doesn't move back, it just stops. Can anyone please help?

```
using UnityEngine;

public class kretanje : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Rigidbody rb; // ime varijable rigidbody koju mozemo kasnije koristiti u programu smo nazvali rb

    public float forwardForce = 0;
    public float sidewayForce = 500f; // to smo stavili da mozemo u inspectoru mijenjati i silu za livo desno 

    // Update is called once per frame
    void FixedUpdate() // dodajemo svaki put kad se zelimo igrat s fizikom (dodavanje sile, gasnje gravitacije...)
    {   // dodaj silu za unaprijed 
        rb.AddForce(0, 0, forwardForce * Time.deltaTime); // da bi islo isto ako razlicita racunala imajj razlicite timeframove

        if (Input.GetKey("d"))
        {
            rb.AddForce(sidewayForce * Time.deltaTime, 0, 0);
        }

        if (Input.GetKey("a"))
        {
            rb.AddForce(-sidewayForce * Time.deltaTime, 0, 0);
        }

        if (Input.GetKey("w"))
        {
            rb.AddForce(0, forwardForce * Time.deltaTime, 0);
        }

        if(Input.GetKey("s"))
        {
            rb.AddForce(0, -forwardForce * Time.deltaTime, 0);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Anyways, welcome to stack overflow. The code shown in the question does not result in the described behavior when I try it. Please edit the question to include a [mre]. Please see the section **Help others reproduce the problem** on our [How do I ask a good question"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) help page.

Comment: @Ruzihm oh.. :D then it is just really confusing naming or a typo here ^^

Comment: Oh and well ... your `forwardforce` is `0` by default .. did you actually change it from the Inspector?

Comment: @Ruzihm I'm actually going for typo in the code posted here .. the comment (translated via Google) sounds like it is supposed to add a forward force ^^ looks like the others should go in Z direction as well .. so I guess you could undelete your answer :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're always adding a force forward (`rb.AddForce(0, 0, forwardForce * Time.deltaTime)`), and even if you press <kbd>s</kbd> you never add enough force in the opposite direction to overcome it.  So, add more force than that when pressing <kbd>s</kbd>. Or, maybe better yet, don't add that force if <kbd>s</kbd> is being pressed:

```
if (!Input.GetKey("s"))
{
    // da bi islo isto ako razlicita racunala imajj razlicite timeframove
    rb.AddForce(0f, 0f, forwardForce * Time.deltaTime); 
}
else
{
    rb.AddForce(0f, 0f, -forwardForce * Time.deltaTime);
}

if (Input.GetKey("w"))
{
    rb.AddForce(0f, 0f, forwardForce * Time.deltaTime);
}

if (Input.GetKey("d"))
{
    rb.AddForce(sidewayForce * Time.deltaTime, 0f, 0f);
}

if (Input.GetKey("a"))
{
    rb.AddForce(-sidewayForce * Time.deltaTime, 0f, 0f);
}
```

By the way, by default you can use `Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical")` to calculate W/S pressing and `Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal")` to calculate A/D pressing:

```
float vertical = Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical");
float horizontal = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal");

if (vertical >= 0f)
{
    rb.AddForce(0f, 0f, forwardForce * Time.deltaTime); 
}

rb.AddForce(horizontal * sidewayForce * Time.deltaTime, 0f,
        forward * forwardForce * Time.deltaTime);
```

You can see Unity's [Input Manager](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-InputManager.html) documentation for more information.